# mysqli_query AND with 3 ORs, not sure how to place them.

Tags: php

Just a quick question, i am not sure how to search it, so hopefulyl there wont be a duplicate.

I am wondering if i want to search the database, definitely needing the userid, then any of (A or B or C), how would i write it?

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM list WHERE userid = '$userid'  
     AND Status = 'A','B',"C' ")or die( mysqli_error($con));
```

I know the above is wrong, but not sure how to change it

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put it like this, when you have a set of things like this `'A', 'B', 'C'` you can use `IN` keyword to tell mysql that you want to search a value that exists in the set you have. Additionally you had a typo in your query you are using `"` before the `C` when you should be using `'`, single quote not double quote.

```
 $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM list WHERE userid = '$userid'  
 AND Status IN ('A','B','C')") or die( mysqli_error($con));
```

the above query is the same as:

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM list WHERE userid = '$userid'  
 AND (Status='A' OR Status='B' OR status='C')") or die( mysqli_error($con));
```